# PyAudio callback not running during blocking operation

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio, kaldi

I'm writing an audio processing script which listens for audio and runs speech recognition on it.
I'm using a PyAudio callback function to capture audio frames and trigger recording/stop when the audio level is above a certain threshold.

The problem is that whenever speech recognition is running on a clip (in the main loop), the callback does not seem to run. This is confusing because I believe that the callback runs in a separate thread.
If I replace the line `speech = get_text(samples)` with `time.sleep(10)`, then the callback continues to be called whilst the main loop blocks.
The callback also continues to work fine when I do something else like compute `math.sin` for 10 seconds.

My question is, what could possibly cause the callback to stop running in its own thread whilst running arbitrary code in the main thread, whilst `time.sleep` allows it?

```py
def audio_callback(self, in_data, frame_count, time_info, flag):
        """ This gets called whenever the audio stream receives new data. """
    rms = audioop.rms(in_data, 2)
    if rms > AUDIO_TRIGGER_LEVEL:
        logger.debug("Recording")
        self.recording = True
        self.recording_quiet_count = 0
    else:
        if self.recording:
            self.recording_quiet_count += 1
        if self.recording_quiet_count > QUIET_CHUNKS_BEFORE_STOP:
            logger.debug("Stopping recording")
            self.recording = False
            self.recording_quiet_count = 0
            self.data_to_process = True

    if self.recording:
        self.recorded_frames.append(in_data)
    return ('', pyaudio.paContinue)

def run(self):
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.05)
        if self.data_to_process:
            logger.debug("Processing recording")
            tot_frames = CHUNK_SIZE * len(self.recorded_frames)
            frames = b''.join(self.recorded_frames)
            self.recorded_frames = []
            self.data_to_process = False
            samples = struct.unpack_from('<%dh' % tot_frames, frames)

            # This is the part causing issues
            speech = get_text(samples)
            # time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Do you found the solution. I have the same problem in my application. the callback thread seems blocked. After few minutes it start to working again.